# Environment with a mandatory or optional argument behind the \end{env}

Tags: environments, xparse, arguments

I would like to create a custom environment, let's say `foo`, with an optional and a mandatory argument. This could be an approach:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{O{default} m}{start #1 #2}{end}
```

This environment could be used like that:

```
\begin{foo}[optional value]{mandatory value}
    text
\end{foo}
```

But I prefer the following method, which I could not implement:

```
\begin{foo}[optional value]
    text
\end{foo}{mandatory value}
```

Is it possible to create such an environment, where the mandatory argument follows the end-clause?

Comment: I’d advise you against this idea, but a use case might possibly clear up the matter.

Comment: @egreg In my case `text` is a latin text and the mandatory value is its translation, the optional contains pgf keys. I have to combine the two texts (latin and translation) in one command/environment, because the formatting of both texts depends on the same pgf keys. (I could use a command `\foo[key]{text}{translation}`, which I find ugly when having long texts and which is inconsistent to my other environments.) To keep the order text+translation, I prefer this last position. I know, it's a little bit special...

Comment: Wouldn't something like `\begin{foo}[<options>] Text \BREAK Translation \end{foo}` be better? With a better name than `\BREAK`, of course.

Comment: I think it looks very strange to have one text in an enviornment body and one in an argument, either use two environments or two arguments or as egreg suggests a single enviornment with a separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the use case as clarified in comments I would use a more symmetric markup using an environment form for both texts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{O{}}
{\gdef\lastsettings{#1}\section*{with settings: #1}\quote}
{\endquote}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo2}{}
{\section*{with reused settings: \lastsettings}\quote}
{\endquote}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}[optional value]
    text
\end{foo}
\begin{foo2}
   translated text
\end{foo2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both solutions (egreg's and David Carlisle's) are great. Thank you! The separator solution is nicely clean. The solution of two environments with transfer of options has the advantage that I can easily separately check, if one body is empty, e.g. if there is one translation or not (i.e. if there has to be a tcolorbox around the translation or not.) I will think about both.