# Environment with lstlisting inside

Tags: listings, environments, latex3

Leaning from [Macro with lstlisting inside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376041/macro-with-lstlisting-inside), I construct my environment `drenv` with `lstlisting` inside. But it doesn't work. How to improve my code to make it work?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{drenv}{m +v O{}}
{
\begin{minipage}{#1}
  \exp_args:Nx \scantokens%
  {
    \string\begin{lstlisting}[\unexpanded{#3}]
       #2
    \string\end{lstlisting}
  }
\end{minipage}
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{drenv}{6in}
some code\rule{1in}{5pt}\par
\fbox{frame box}
\end{drenv}[xleftmargin=2in]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
According to the third solution in the answer(by `\lstnewenvironment`), I tried the follow codes, and fails either. What's wrong and how to make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}
%------------------------------
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{dr}{O{}m}
{
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  \begin{minipage}{#2}
}
{
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \colorbox{#1}{\usebox\mybox}
}
\lstnewenvironment{drenv}[3][]
 {
   \dr[#2]{#3}
   \lstset{#1}
 }
 {
   \enddr
 }
%------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{drenv}{red}{5in}
\rule{2in}{5pt}
\end{drenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. Why are you using lstlisting if the code inside is not verbatim?  -- in other words, explain what output do you want by writing the code "by hand" without using a custom environment wrapper.

Comment: Side note, "copy paste" LaTeX code with modification will almost never work. Better understand what each command does and write your own code based on the solution. (if you want to use scantokens you should really truly understand [tex core - Use of \everyeof and \endlinechar with \scantokens - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117906) and [tex core - New lines and TeX: difference between ^^J and ^^M - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8967/new-lines-and-tex-difference-between-j-and-m?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @user202729 I want to wrap `lstlisting` into another environment(`minipage` here is only an example, it maybe `list`, `enumerate` etc). In this outer environment, I can setup something(width, position, color, contrast result ...)

Comment: Let me ask again, what do you want the result of this particular MWE to be? Type it out directly using lstlisting, without defining an auxiliary environment.

Comment: I want to typeset #2 as verbatim just like what is done in the link  ` Macro with lstlisting inside` and use `minipage` to control the width in this example.

Comment: So e.g. you want to put literally the text `\rule{1in}{5pt}` inside the lstlisting block, instead of a rule?

Comment: Yes. all the content of #2 as it is as verbatim. In this example ,it should be `some code\rule{1in}{5pt}\par
\fbox{frame box}`(includeing breaklines in the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `newverbs` to collect the environment body, write it to a file, then `\input` it.

Note that `newverbs` unfortunately might do some unexpected things with the literal TAB character (convert to space or removed).
Nevertheless if you write to file instead of `\scantokens`, XeTeX will have problem with TAB characters anyway: [write - How to output a tabulation into a file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/how-to-output-a-tabulation-into-a-file).
Solution using my package below doesn't have this limitation, or you can probably patch it manually if you use newverbs package.

Alternative solution using `\scantokens` is also provided. But this way you can more easily inspect the tempfile when something goes wrong.

Note that the mandatory arg and the optional arg are detokenized (so don't put funny catcode tokens there), and I assume that no optional arg is equivalent to empty optional arg.

The syntax is a little different, both to make the implementation easier, and arg after environment end is not really a good idea anyway [xparse - Environment with a mandatory or optional argument behind the \end{env} - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634542/environment-with-a-mandatory-or-optional-argument-behind-the-endenv).

(not that it's impossible to implement the other things. Just that I don't really see the point of doing it)

Having a final optional argument omitted will probably confuse newverbs, see [spacing - NewDocumentEnvironment optional argument changes behaviour with \obeylines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649331/newdocumentenvironment-optional-argument-changes-behaviour-with-obeylines/649333#649333), so I put it before the mandatory argument.

**The code in this answer does not obey expl3's naming convention** (e.g. `__tempwrite` should be `\g_lyl_tempwrite_file` where the `lyl` is your own prefix. See expl3.pdf for more details). Use at your own risk.

By the way, you'd better not storing important document into a file named `tempfile.tex` otherwise you're going to have problems.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \__tempwrite

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__processcontent:nnn #1 #2 #3 {
    % #1 is the mandatory argument of the environment
    % #2 is the verbatim content of the environment body
    % #3 is the optional argument
    \tl_set:Nn \__content {
        \begin{minipage}{#1} ^^J
            \begin{lstlisting}[#3] ^^J
               #2 ^^J
    }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \__content { \string \end }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \__content {
            {lstlisting} ^^J
        \end{minipage}
    }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__processcontent:nnn {VVV}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__continue: {
    \str_replace_all:Nxn \__saved_environment_body  {\cs_to_str:N \^^M} {^^J}
    \__processcontent:VVV \__saved_mandatory_arg \__saved_environment_body \__saved_optional_arg

    \iow_open:Nn \__tempwrite {tempfile.tex}
    \exp_args:NNV \iow_now:Nn \__tempwrite \__content
    \iow_close:N \__tempwrite
    \input {tempfile.tex}

    % the 4 lines above can be replaced by::
    %\exp_args:NV \scantokens \__content
    %in that case the iow_new:N would be unnecessary
}



\NewDocumentEnvironment{drenv}{O{}m}
{
    \collectverbenv{
        \str_gset:Nn \__saved_optional_arg {#1}
        \str_gset:Nn \__saved_mandatory_arg {#2}
        \str_gset:Nn \__saved_environment_body
    }
}{
    \__continue:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{drenv}[xleftmargin=2in]{6in}
some code\rule{1in}{5pt}\par
\fbox{frame  box}
\end{drenv}
\end{document}
```

Output is as you expect...

[image: output image]

It's not explicitly documented in newverbs.pdf that endlinechar is active char 13, but it is the case.

It's also not documented in interface3.pdf that `\iow_now:n` will force newlinechar=10, but it is the case. (x-expanding the `\iow_newline:` token is the only documented safe way)

---

*Package advertisements*:

Personally, I don't like it when I have to use elaborate hacks to get tokens with weird catcode into the token list, so I wrote a package precattl for this.

Also for the purpose of collecting environment body verbatim there's also my package saveenv.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{saveenv}
\usepackage{precattl}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \__tempwrite

\precattl_exec:n {
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__processcontent:nnn #1 #2 #3 {
    % #1 is the mandatory argument of the environment
    % #2 is the verbatim content of the environment body
    % #3 is the optional argument
    \tl_set:Nn \__content {
        \begin{minipage}{#1} ^^J
            \cO\\begin{lstlisting}[#3] ^^J
               #2 ^^J
            \cO\\end{lstlisting} ^^J
        \end{minipage}
    }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__processcontent:nnn {nV}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{drenv}{O{}m}
{
    \saveenv \__saved_environment_body
}{
    \endsaveenv

    \str_replace_all:Nnn \__saved_environment_body  {\cO\^^M} {^^J}
    \__processcontent:nVn {#2} \__saved_environment_body {#1}

    \iow_open:Nn \__tempwrite {tempfile.tex}
    \exp_args:NNV \iow_now:Nn \__tempwrite \__content
    \iow_close:N \__tempwrite
    \input {tempfile.tex}

    % the 4 lines above can be replaced by::
    %\exp_args:NV \scantokens \__content
    %in that case the iow_new:N would be unnecessary
}

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{drenv}[xleftmargin=2in]{6in}
some code\rule{1in}{5pt}\par
\fbox{frame  box}
\end{drenv}
\end{document}
```

---

For the purpose of this particular new environment, you actually don't need to rescan the tokens, `lstnewenvironment` can be used instead:

```
\lstnewenvironment{drenv}[2][]
 {
 \minipage {#2}
 \lstset{#1}
 }
 {
            \endminipage
 }
```

Usage is identical to the above.

Comment: Many thanks for these wonderfue solutions!! And I just make an edit of my question. Would you have a look at it?

Comment: @lyl Not sure. You might need to use the [plain form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14683/250119) (although it becomes a different question already...?), or lstnewenvironment might simply not support that; in that case do the auxiliary file/scantokens approach.